# check if element with certain data-attr exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check if this element with a specific data-option:

```
<area data-option="anyOption" etc.. />
```

exists on my website. I tried this:

```
if ($("area[data-option = 'anyOption']")[0]) {
```

but this doesnt work..any idea´s about this problem?

Greetings!

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. The only suggestion I might make is to remove the single quotes around the attribute value: `if ($("area[data-option=anyOption]").length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  if ($('area[data-option = "anyOption"]').length) {
      alert("exists");
  }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if($('area[data-option="anyOption"]').length > 0){
  console.log("exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $("area").attr("data-option");  
if(data =="anyOption")
{
//Code here
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2nXGd/

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if($('[data-option="anyOption"]') !== []){
  // do something
}
```

jquery returns an empty array when nothing matches. So just compare it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could find out if ANY areas with defined data-options exist with:

```
$("area[data-option]").length > 0
```

or check for a specific one with:

```
$("area[data-option=anyoption]").length > 0
```